# Using a module's definition in Coq

Tags: coq

The following code states that it defines finite sets in Coq with the axiom of extensionality:

```
(** A library for finite sets with extensional equality.

    Author: Brian Aydemir. *)

Require Import FSets.
Require Import ListFacts.
Require Import Coq.Logic.ProofIrrelevance.


(* *********************************************************************** *)
(** * Interface *)

(** The following interface wraps the standard library's finite set
    interface with an additional property: extensional equality. *)

Module Type S.

  Declare Module E : UsualOrderedType.
  Declare Module F : FSetInterface.S with Module E := E.

  Parameter eq_if_Equal :
    forall s s' : F.t, F.Equal s s' -> s = s'.

End S.


(* *********************************************************************** *)
(** * Implementation *)

(** For documentation purposes, we hide the implementation of a
    functor implementing the above interface.  We note only that the
    implementation here assumes (as an axiom) that proof irrelevance
    holds. *)

Module Make (X : UsualOrderedType) <: S with Module E := X.

  (* begin hide *)

  Module E := X.
  Module F := FSetList.Make E.
  Module OFacts := OrderedType.OrderedTypeFacts E.

  Lemma eq_if_Equal :
    forall s s' : F.t, F.Equal s s' -> s = s'.
  Proof.
    intros [s1 pf1] [s2 pf2] Eq.
    assert (s1 = s2).
      unfold F.MSet.Raw.t in *.
      eapply Sort_InA_eq_ext; eauto.
      intros; eapply E.lt_trans; eauto.
      1 : {
        apply F.MSet.Raw.isok_iff.
        auto.
      }
      1 : {
        apply F.MSet.Raw.isok_iff.
        auto.
      }
    subst s1.
    assert (pf1 = pf2).
    apply proof_irrelevance.
    subst pf2.
    reflexivity.
  Qed.

  (* end hide *)

End Make.
```

How can I define a function with signature from finite sets to finite sets using this module?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `Module` (call it `M`) that implements the `UsualOrderedType` module type for the type you want to make finite sets out of, and then build another `Module` with `Make M` which contains an implementation of finite sets for your type.

```
Module M <: UsualOrderedType.
   ...
End M.
Module foo := Make M.
Check foo.F.singleton.
```

Note that you need to declare the module type with `<:` instead of just `:`, otherwise you are hiding the fact that the module is defined for (in the example below) `nat` behind an opaque type `t`.

Say you want to make finite sets of `nat`s:

```
(* Print the module type to see all the things you need to define. *)

Print Module Type UsualOrderedType. 

Require Import PeanonNat.

Module NatOrdered <: UsualOrderedType .   (* note the `<:` *)
  Definition t:=nat.
  Definition eq:=@eq nat.
  Definition lt:=lt.
  Definition eq_refl:=@eq_refl nat.
  Definition eq_sym:=@eq_sym nat.
  Definition eq_trans:=@eq_trans nat.
  Definition lt_trans:=Nat.lt_trans.
  (* I wrote Admitted where I didn't provide an implementation *)
  Definition lt_not_eq : forall x y : t, lt x y -> ~ eq x y. Admitted.
  Definition compare : forall x y : t, Compare lt eq x y. Admitted.
  Definition eq_dec : forall x y : t, {eq x y} + {~ eq x y}. Admitted.
End NatOrdered.
```

Now you can create a module that uses this ordered type.

```
Module foo := Make NatOrdered.

Print foo.F.  (* to see everything that is defined for the FSetList *)
Import foo.  (* get F in our namespace so we can say F.t instead of foo.F.t, etc. *)
```

Now we can use our `F` module.  The finite sets have type `F.t` and the elements have type `F.elt` which is coercible to `nat` since we know they come from `NatOrdered`.

Lets build a function that uses stuff from `F`.

```
Definition f: F.elt -> F.t.
  intros x. apply (F.singleton x).
Defined.

Print F.
Goal F.cardinal (F.union (f 1) (f 2)) = 2.
  compute.
```

Ok. That gets stuck halfway through the computation because I didn't implement `compare` above. I was lazy and just wrote `Admitted.`  But you can do it! :-)